# interpretacion de error en c++

Tags: c++

bueno sucede que estaba haciendo un programa para calcula la suma , resta, multiplicacion de 2 numeros mediante el uso de funciones pero me sale este error y no se como solucionarlo el programa esta hecho en dev-c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por cierto alguien sabe como puedo recuperar la venta de la parte de abajo de dev-c++ para ver la descripcion mas detallada de los errores se los agradeceria mucho ya que si eso es aun mas dificil saber que error estoy cometiendo.

Edito: el código de error es el siguiente

> E0109 la expresión incluida delante del paréntesis de la llamada aparente debe tener un tipo de puntero a función

Comment: "*me sale este error*" ¿ **qué error** ? En la captura de pantalla no sale. ¿Podrías cambiar la captura de pantalla por el código que te falla?

Comment: Como dice @PaperBirdMaster, sustituye la captura de pantalla por código que se pueda copiar y pegar y tendrás la respuesta al por qué de tu problema. Las imágenes son problemáticas porque dificultan que quien te intenta ayudar copie tu código para analizarlo y hacer pruebas... eso sin contar con que si la imagen deja de estar disponible porque se borra del servidor donde está alojada tu pregunta va a quedar totalmente inservible

Comment: pienso que su problema esta aqui -> `suma = suma(...);` puede cambiar `int suma` en el main por otro nombre igual ese es su error, por otro lado tenga presente los comentarios sobre la imagen. aunque se solucione seria mejor que actualice su pregunta y es muy probable que le alguien le explique el problema mas detalladamente. Saludos

Comment: carlos, en vez de una captura de pantalla, puedes [edit] tu pregunta colocar el código fuente _"no necesariamente todo, solo las líneas que te generan error"_.

Comment: Gracias por sus consejos y comentarios, en efecto el error radicaba en que el nombre de las variables(las que utilizo para llamar a las funciones)  y el de las funciones debian ser diferentes.

Comment: no es suma=suma(a,b) sino suma(a,b); directamente sin asignación.